# Array is getting index out of bounds in one specific spot of text file

Tags: java

So I have a text file with very simple text. Each line is simply make,model,vin#. I have about 3 or 4 lines to test. When I print out these lines, only the lines with even indexes get printed. If I don't include the else statement then it gives an out of bounds exception. So for example, with text file input as shown

Hi guys. I have a text file that is only a few lines long. On each line, it is formatted as such:`make,model,number`. When I run my program, it prints the lines normally until it gets to the third line of the text file(there's only 5 lines). This third line is where I get the `index out of bounds exception`.

```
public CarDealershipSystem(File carFile, File associateFile) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(carFile))) {
        String line;
        for(;;) {
            line = br.readLine();
            String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(lineArray[0]);
            System.out.println(lineArray[1]);
            System.out.println(lineArray[2]);
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: just remove `if` statement.

Comment: I've removed the if statement and tried your method but I get an index oob exception. I'll edit my code to what I changed it to.

Comment: yes lineArray length is less than 2 the index out of bound exception could happen

Comment: It shouldn't be less than 2 though. Weird thing is whenever I run my program, a different error occurs each time. It seems like there are different index oob exceptions that catch in different parts of my code when I run the program multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need a break when you reach the end of the file.

```java
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //stop loop when line == null
            line = br.readLine();
       }
```

2. you need to check your input, before split

```java
String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
if (lineArray != null && lineArray.length == 3) { //will help you avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception 
            System.out.println(lineArray[0]);
            System.out.println(lineArray[1]);
            System.out.println(lineArray[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe this worked. I'm not quite sure why it didn't work before(I've tried that and many different things). It seems as soon as I added my input under the if statement you wrote it magically started working. Thanks again

Comment: You can try to debug,  I guess the problem is on the `line` variable. It's null or empty caused the exception

Answer (score 2):

You have "line = br.readLine()" in two places in "while" cycle and in "if" block that causes two calls to readLine per cycle. Besides this block is pointless because the "while" condition already handles it.

tldr: remove

```
if((line = br.readLine()) == null) {
                break;
            }
```